# Bootstrap Carousel Firefox Positioning

Tags: css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap, positioning

I am using the Bootstrap Carousel on my site - everything is working as expected - only Firefox is making trouble.

The .carousel-inner is only shown when I set:

```
.carousel-inner{ 
    overflow:visible;
    width:auto;
}
```

But now the scrollbars are showing up in every other browser, when the animation is running.
Keeping it like

```
.carousel-inner{ 
    overflow:hidden;
    width:auto;
}
```

will hide the scrollbars, but the whole div gets positioned to the right somehow in FF.

Where is my error, where did I mess up, or is this a FF positioning bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the problem in Firefox is this:

```
.carousel {
    margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
}
```

Specifically, the negative `margin-top`.

Comment: You should probably also remove this: `.carousel .item { margin: -1px 0 0 -1px; }`.

Comment: as simple as that. Thanks.